# windows app, using SQL Server, need to it work on PCs on a different domain

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

Part of our company has moved to another area and they are being set up as a separate domain. The users can VPN in to our domain to run the app, but when they try to access the database it fails, because SQL Server is set for Windows Authentication, and they are on a different domain. It is a Windows C# app, we are using SQL Server 2005 Express, I could set this for mixed mode Authentication but I'm still not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Sounds like a Server Fault / Super User question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download and install [SQL Server 2005 Management Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796&displaylang=en). Once installed, open it from a pc under your domain, and go to Security->Users->SA user->Properties.

Set a password for it and set its state to "Actvated". You can use its account info to login from wichever domain you have to. 
If you want, setup a new user instead of use SA: Sa is very powerful user, and you can mitigate security issue  allowing only normal users to access from extern.

To use your new user info, you have to edit your connection string, changing

```
Integrated Security=True
```

to

```
Integrated Security=False;User=YourUserHere;Password=YourPasswordHere
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use SQL Server authentication for this. You can connect via windows authentication by starting up management studio as follows (obviously the path might need adjusting your end)

```
 runas /user:OTHERDOMAIN\OTHERUSERNAME  /netonly 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWb.exe"
```